# Does an ADT have multiple or only one representations/implementations?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

Section 24.2  in *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce defines ADTs in existential types:

> **A conventional abstract data type (or ADT)** consists of (1) a type name A, (2) a concrete representation type T, (3) implementations of
>   some operations for creating, querying, and manipulating values of
>   type T, and (4) an abstraction boundary enclosing the representation
>   and operations. Inside this boundary, elements of the type are viewed
>   concretely (with type T). Outside, they are viewed abstractly, with
>   type A. Values of type A may be passed around, stored in data
>   structures, etc., but not directly examined or changed—the only
>   operations allowed on A are those provided by the ADT. ... We ﬁrst
>   create an existential package containing the internals of the ADT:
>
> ```
> counterADT =
> {*Nat,
> {new = 1,
> get = λi:Nat. i,
> inc = λi:Nat. succ(i)}}
> as {∃Counter,
> {new: Counter,
> get: Counter→Nat,
> inc: Counter→Counter}};
>
> > counterADT : {∃Counter,
> {new:Counter,get:Counter→Nat,inc:Counter→Counter}}
> ```
>
> We can open it for example
>
> ```
> let {Counter,counter} = counterADT in
> counter.get (counter.inc counter.new);
> > 2 : Nat
> ```

Does the highlighted sentence in the following quote say that a ADT can have multiple representations/implementations?

> A key property of the kind of information hiding we are doing here is
>   representation independence. **We can substitute an alternative
>   implementation of the Counter ADT**—for example, one where the
>   internal representation is a record containing a Nat rather than just
>   a single Nat,
>
> ```
> counterADT =
> {*{x:Nat},
> {new = {x=1},
> get = λi:{x:Nat}. i.x,
> inc = λi:{x:Nat}. {x=succ(i.x)}}}
> as {∃Counter,
> {new: Counter, get: Counter→Nat, inc: Counter→Counter}};
>
> > counterADT : {∃Counter,
> {new:Counter,get:Counter→Nat,inc:Counter→Counter}}
> ```
>
> in complete conﬁdence that the whole program will remain typesafe,
>   since we are guaranteed that the rest of the program cannot access
>   instances of Counter except using get and inc.

Do the highlighted sentences in the following two quotes say that an ADT can have only one representation/implementation?

On p377:

> In summary, **the single representations of ADTs** directly support
>   binary operations, while the multiple representations of objects give
>   up binary meth- ods in return for useful ﬂexibility. These advantages
>   are complementary; nei- ther style dominates the other.

From [a reply to my previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/113574/336):

> **ADTs are entirely public about their unique representation.** Belonging in the ADT means satisfying said representation, and so binary methods can rightfully assume that both operands have that exact representation.

Why is the inconsistency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ADT is a *specification*. It can have many *implementations*. For an example, see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/113357/683).

Comment: Thanks. Just added more context. Why do the last two quotes seem to say an ADT can have only one representation?

Comment: As I explained in a comment to a past question, I take issue with this kind of close reading of TAPL.